# DB schema design: how to add `select-all` functionality for a 1:N relationship column?

Tags: mysql, jpa, database-design

I am having `company` table which is having a `1:N` relationship with the `category` table. `category` has around ~250 records and is marked `NOT NULL` in `company`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company` (
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `company_company_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
  INDEX `fk_category_company_idx` (`company_company_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_category_company`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_company_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`company` (`company_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

This works fine if I want to select one or more(limited) categories for the company, but I am confused on how to add a **Select All** feature. If for **Select All** I choose all of the ~200 categories, that would blow up the response. This is a part of a REST api and sending all ~200 categories over the network seems a foolish idea.
I could think of removing the `1:N` relationship and hold the categories into a `JSON` column but then I would lose the data integrity.

How can I solve this? Adding a new column? Any ideal way, please.

Answer (score 1):

`company.category_id` indicates at category-to-company is 1:N, not the other way around. If I am understanding your question correctly, and you want companies to have multiple categories, and that pool the categories are chosen from shared across companies. You're needing represent and M:N relationship. For that you need a linking table:

```
CREATE TABLE `company_category` (
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`, `category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_company_category_company`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`company` (`company_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_company_category_category`
    FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`category` (`category_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

You'd also remove `category_id` from the `company` table in this model.

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly put the FK on `company`. Edited and corrected. From your answer as `M:N`, the question remains the same, is sending ~200 categories over the response a good choice?

Comment: If you need the information, you need the information. Another benefit of using an M:N model is that since all companies share the same pool of categories, the client only has to have one local copy of the category information, and company data can be sent with only category id. The only time full category data need be sent/retrieved is when updating information about the categories themselves, or getting the current information for initialization/refresh of local reference.

Answer (score 0):

One company can have zero or many categories, and one category can be shared across multiple companies. Hence, the relation is "many-to-many". You are missing a link table between companies and categories:

```
companies
---------
company_id (PK)
name

categories
----------
category_id (PK)
name

company_categories
------------------
company_id
category_id
PK: company_id, category_id
```